# error of "You don't currently have permission to access this folder" from osfmount when opening \users\user from a raw file produced by dd

Tags: dd

I'm getting an error of "You don't currently have permission to access this folder" from osfmount when opening \users\user(or whatever user profile folder), from a raw file produced by dd (or ddrescue).

When trying to open c:\user\usera , it takes a while, then I get "You don't currently have permission to access this folder"

If I choose continue then after a while, it says "You have been denied permission to access this folder"   and "To gain access you will need to use the security tab".

If I then click the blue text where it says security tab, it opens the properties for the usera folder.  Has an button" continue, and says permissions for usera

[image]

Then I get messages like this "An error occurred while applying security information to:....  The media is write protected"

[image]

If I keep clicking "continue", it just keeps flashing up about more files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works  https://forums.passmark.com/osforensics-osfmount-osfclone/3834-osfmount-access-denied-to-parts-of-disk-image

There's an option in this screen

[image]

Have "Read only" not ticked.

Then it works.

It does seem to take a while(maybe a minute), to open %userprofile% of the image, but once it's open then it opens quickly.

Possibly TestDisk could also do it as that can read a dd image, and people use that to open it read only and copy files from it.

Also https://forums.passmark.com/osforensics-osfmount-osfclone/3834-osfmount-access-denied-to-parts-of-disk-image  mentions that they have a program called osforensics that can be used.